# Is there a compelling reason to use PHP's operator === in comparison operations, over ==?

Tags: php, operators, equals-operator

Say I have this code:

```
$str = '5';
$int = 5;
```

For comparison, is there any reason to use something like this (with conversion):

```
if ($int === intval($str)) //...
```

or do I just use native PHP facilities?

```
if ($int == $str) //...
```

To me, `==` looks simpler, perhaps at the expense of having PHP do the extra work for me.

Comment: If you don't care about the data type, there is no reason to use ===. If you do care about the data type, you will want to use ===. So, I reserve === only when data type is important. Then, if I see a === in my code, I know it is there for a very good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are trying to do.  Some functions might return `false` or `0` or a positive integer, like `strpos()`. `0` means the string was found at position `0` so `== false` would not work as `=== false`.

In your scenario it is fine to use `==` as this is common when getting values from a DB or `$_POST` and `$_GET`, they will always be strings.

Thanks to the comment from Fred Emmott:  Be careful, the following return `true`:

```
var_dump('0xa' == '10');   // 0xa hex 10 in decimal
var_dump('10pigs' == 10);  // pigs truncated
```

See [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: Just to clarify: == is not safe for arbitrary strings - eg:

      $x = '0e462097431906509019562988736854';
      $y = '0e830400451993494058024219903391';
      var_dump($x == $y); // true

More detailed example in separate answer below

http://3v4l.org/a6DZC

Answer (score 1):

Using '==' tends to lead to subtle bugs - eg if two strings look like numbers, PHP does not compare them as strings, which can give unexpected results - the most common/scary example is:

```
<?php

$actual_password = '240610708';
$provided_password = 'QNKCDZO';

// These would presumably be stored in your database
$stored_password_md5 = md5($actual_password); //0e462097431906509019562988736854;
$stored_password_hash = password_hash($actual_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$computed_password_md5 = md5($provided_password); //0e830400451993494058024219903391

var_dump($stored_password_md5 == $computed_password_md5); // bool(true) - BAD! NO!
var_dump($stored_password_md5 === $computed_password_md5); // bool(false) - Better, but still no. Vulnerable to timing attacks
var_dump(hash_equals($stored_password_md5, $computed_password_md5)); // bool(false) getting somewhere
var_dump(password_verify($provided_password, $stored_password_hash)); // bool(false) best
```

While in your specific example, this problem doesn't occur, the possible problems lead to a lot of people recommending to /always/ use ===, so you don't have to remember when == is safe and when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The == operator just checks to see if the left and right values are equal. But, the === operator (note the extra “=”) actually checks to see if the left and right values are equal, and also checks to see if they are of the same variable type (like whether they are both booleans, ints, etc.).